# Elastic Db tools and unique indexes

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database, multi-tenant

I read the documentation for the Microsoft Elastic DB tools and I wanted to ask what are the best practices for sharing a database with multiple tenants and also using unique index.

Let's say that we have a users table, in which all users for a tenant are saved. We define that the email must be unique for each user. But, If a user is present in 2 tenants and he wants to reuse his email, he can't because the unique index is in place.

In this case, we need to include in the unique index the tenant id. Is this the right approach? In this case we would need to  explicitly use the tenant id in all of our queries so that the performance is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, including the tenant id in each sharded table is a common practice in SaaS programming models. Here is some context on the spectrum of multi-tenant per database to single tenant per database models for SaaS applications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-patterns-multi-tenancy-saas-applications#multitenant-data-models

Comment: I know this documentation. My question is more related to best practices in the multi tenant database design. As an example, how to handle unique indexes